# For loop does not print numbers that end with 0?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Suppose that 'i' is 90 and 90%10 = 0, it does not print 90.

```
numbers = [1,100]
for i in numbers:
    if i%10 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
100
```

Should be: 10, 20 ... 100?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be. You need a `range` between those numbers. `for i in numbers` literally just considers the two numbers in your list.

Comment: The list elements are 1 and 100, not 90.

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow. I separated the code into 4 lines but it comes out as a single line?

Comment: I already fixed it for you. When you post code, post a block, highlight it all and click the `{}` button in the editor or use ctrl + k

Answer (score 3):

Your list only contains the values 1 and 100, not the range of numbers between 1 and 100. Use range instead.

```
numbers = range(1, 100)
```